# Wordpress wp_nonce_url inside a while loop (multiple posts grid)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

In wordpress we have a grid with posts from a custom CPT called Routes.

```
<div class="activities-sections">
 <?php 
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $post_count = 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'routes',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author' => $user_id,
    );
     $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ($query->have_posts()) :?>
        <div class="activities-container">
            <div class="activities-wrap">
                <?php 
              while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="activities-box-list">
                  <div class="activities-box">
                      <div class="activities-img">
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?> </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="activities-content">
                            <div class="card-heading-destinations">
                              <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                              <span class="icon-heading" style="border-bottom:2px solid <?php the_field('choose_border_color'); ?>">
                                  <?php $icon_heading = get_field('heading_icon');
                                    if($icon_heading): echo '<img src="'.$icon_heading.'">'; ?>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-paragraph">
                              <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo substr($excerpt, 0, 300)."" ;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-dest-post"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">ΔΕΙΤΕ ΑΝΑΛΥΤΙΚΑ 
                            <span class="button-icon">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="37" height="33.002" viewBox="0 0 37 33.002">
                                <defs>
                                <filter id="eye_icon" x="0" y="0" width="37" height="33.002" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                <feOffset dy="4" input="SourceAlpha"/>
                                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" result="blur"/>
                                <feFlood flood-opacity="0.078"/>
                                <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
                                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
                                </filter>
                                </defs>
                                <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#eye_icon)">
                                <path id="eye_icon-2" data-name="eye icon" d="M430,3901s-3.582,6-8,6-8-6-8-6h0s3.582-6,8-6,8,6,8,6h0Zm-8-5c-2.848,0-5.621,3.235-6.81,4.995.932,1.364,3.712,5.006,6.81,5.006,2.848,0,5.621-3.234,6.81-5C427.878,3899.64,425.1,3896,422,3896Zm0,9a4,4,0,1,1,4-4A4,4,0,0,1,422,3905Zm0-7a3,3,0,1,0,3,3A3,3,0,0,0,422,3898Z" transform="translate(-403.5 -3888.5)" fill="#3c4042"/>
                                </g>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                            
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php
 //$url = get_bloginfo('url');
                                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
  if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)){
echo '<a class="delete-post" href="';
echo wp_nonce_url("$url/wp-admin/post.php?action=trash&post=$post_id", 'delete-post_' .                $post->ID);
echo '">Delete post</a>';
 }
 ?>
                  </div>  
                

                </div>
                <?php 
                endwhile; 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Under each post i want to add a link "Delete post" post so logged in users will be able to delete specific post when clicking on it.

I have used function wp_nonce_url.

The problem is that _wpnonce= generated the same value for all posts in the grid.

For example if i have 10 posts in the loop _wpnonce= will always will be _wpnonce=10a2e64a4b for all 10 posts.

Any idea how to make work correctly in a loop? Any code?

I believe each post must have a unique _wpnonce= so when we click on delete post it will delete the specific post.

Right now when i click delete post on any grid item i get:
"The link you followed has expired.".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Correct way to do this is with  wordpress get_delete_post_link function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_delete_post_link/

Can be used within the WordPress loop or outside of it, with any post type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).